# WildFly 8 Administration Console under Vagrant

Tags: jboss, vagrant, wildfly, wildfly-8

I installed WildFly 8.2.1 under a CentOS image using Vagrant (with Virtualbox). My Vagrantfile includes a line for network forwarding and the "Welcome" page on localhost can be accessed normally in the host machine. When I try to access the Administration Console page, however, I get the following message:

> An automatic redirect to the Administration Console is not currently available. This is most likely due to the administration console being exposed over a network interface different from the one to which you are connected to.

The same URL can be accessed normally when inside the VM. What do I have to do to make it work on the host computer?